# [sonataAdmin]: test the select imput value

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I want to retrieve the value of select input and make the test on this value. If this value corresponds to what I am looking for in my case "freelance" I display a block if no I display another

this is my code:

```
 $emr = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('PivotalBOBundle:Role');
    $queryr = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('PivotalBOBundle:Role')->findAll();

    $choises=array();

    foreach ($queryr as $res){
        $choises[$res->getRole()]=$res->getRole();
    }
->tab('Spécifique')
        ->with('Type d\'utilisateur', array('class' => 'col-md-12'))
        ->add('type', 'choice', array('label' => 'Type',
            'choices' => $choises))
        ->end()

->with('Freelancer', array('class' => 'col-md-12 Freelancer'))
        ->add('type', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Freelancer'))
        ->add('categories', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                "multiple" => true,
                'label' => 'Catégorie',
                'required' => true,
                'query' => $query))
            ->add('outilsEtTechnologie', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                'required' => false,
                "multiple" => true,
                'label' => 'Outils et Technologie'))
            ->add('niveauCompetences', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Niveau des compétences',
                'by_reference' => true), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ))
            ->add('niveauLangue', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Niveau des langues',
                'by_reference' => false), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ))
            ->add('formation', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Formations',
                'by_reference' => false), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ))
            ->add('mobilite', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\Mobilite',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Mobilite'
            ))
            ->add('frequence', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\Frequence',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Frequence'
            ))
            ->add('niveauExperience', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\NiveauExperience',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Niveau Experience'))
            ->add('missionetranger', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\Missionetranger',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Mission Etranger'))
            ->add('note', null, array('label' => 'Note'))
        ->end()
        ->with('Jobowner ', array('class' => 'col-md-12 Jobowner'))
        ->add('type', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Jobowner'))
        ->add('societe', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\Societe',
                'property' => 'nom',
                'label' => 'Societe',
                'required' => false,
            ))
        ->end();
```

this is an image of my render [the case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfH2q.png)

and this is my objectif :

[the freelancer option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZeKk.png)

[the jobowner option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZeKk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do this we should use a java script code like this :

```
->tab('Spécifique')
        ->with('Type d\'utilisateur', array('class' => 'col-md-12'))
        ->add('type', 'choice', array('label' => 'Type',
            'choices' => $choises))
        ->end()
        ->with('Freelancer', array('class' => 'col-md-12 userFreelancer'))
        ->add('categories', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                "multiple" => true,
                'label' => 'Catégorie',
                'required' => true,
                'query' => $query))
            ->add('outilsEtTechnologie', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                'required' => false,
                "multiple" => true,
                'label' => 'Outils et Technologie'))
            ->add('niveauCompetences', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Niveau des compétences',
                'by_reference' => true), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ))
            ->add('niveauLangue', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Niveau des langues',
                'by_reference' => false), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ))
            ->add('formation', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Formations',
                'by_reference' => false), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ))
            ->add('mobilite', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\Mobilite',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Mobilite'
            ))
            ->add('frequence', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\Frequence',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Frequence'
            ))
            ->add('niveauExperience', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\NiveauExperience',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Niveau Experience'))
            ->add('missionetranger', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\Missionetranger',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Mission Etranger'))
            ->add('note', null, array('label' => 'Note'))
        ->end();

        $formMapper->with('Societe', array('class' => 'col-md-12 Societe'))
            ->add('societe', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Pivotal\BOBundle\Entity\Societe',
                'property' => 'nom',
                'label' => 'Societe',
                'required' => false,
            ))

        ->end()
        ->end();
```

and we should overide the template 
like that :

```
 public function getTemplate($name)
    {
        if ($name == "edit") {
            return 'admin/edit.html.twig';
        }
        return parent::getTemplate($name);
    }
```

and add a javascript code in edit.html.twig :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var type = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_type");
        var freelancer = $(".userFreelancer");
        var jobowner = $(".userJobowner");
        var redacteur = $(".userRedacteur");
        var Supperjobowner = $(".userSupperjobowner");
        var Nactif = $(".userNactif");
        var Societe = $(".Societe");
        hideUserBlock()
        type.change(function () {
            displayUserBlock();
        }); // Bind the function to displayBlock
        type.change(); // Manual trigger to display block.


        function displayUserBlock() {
            hideUserBlock();
            var type =$("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_type").val()
            switch(type) {
                case 'Freelancer':
                    freelancer.css("display", "block");
                    freelancer.trigger("create");
                    break;
                case 'Jobowner':
                    Societe.css("display", "block");
                    Societe.trigger("create");
                    break;
                case 'Super Jobowner':
                    Societe.css("display", "block");
                    Societe.trigger("create");
                    break;
                case 'Jobowner non actif':
                    Societe.css("display", "block");
                    Societe.trigger("create");
                    break;
                case 'Rédacteur':
                    Societe.css("display", "block");
                    Societe.trigger("create");
                    break;
            }

        }

        function hideUserBlock() {
            freelancer.css("display", "none");
            freelancer.trigger("create");
            Societe.css("display", "none");
            Societe.trigger("create");
        }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current subject with `$this->getSubject()`.

So you could modify your Form by using:

```
$subject = $this->getSubject();

// with "Type d'utilisateur"

if ($subject && $subject->getType() === 'freelance') {
    // with "Freelancer"
}

// other tabs/form-fields
```

---

This only works if you gonna re-open your form view. If you need to instantly modify your form if you select "freelance" without reloading the page, you need to write it in Javascript. Depending on your needs, this varies a lot (e.g. hiding the tab/with-section and show it via Javascript).

Comment: can you let me an exemple?